# ASP.Net Website Cannot Rebuild Solution Nor Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, web

I have a crazy issue and need assistance.

I have an ASP.Net Website (v. 4 framework) that all of sudden I cannot Rebuild Solution nor Publish.

When I Rebuild Solution I get a CS0433 error, where

"The type 'ASP.ascx_breadcrumb_ascx' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyAppName\d1db14f7\26574b0c\App_Web_breadcrumb.ascx.c95a9aa.ckg3a1pq.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyAppName\d1db14f7\26574b0c\App_Web_breadcrumb.ascx.c95a9aa.l64cmosr.dll'"

When I Publish Visual Studio (2010 Ultimate) states it succeeded but no *.compile files get created in the bin, which means the site cannot be accessed.

Scouring Google with my colleagues we came across advice to:

- Delete all files under c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Restart IIS
- Remove all files from the site's bin
- Restart development machine

I have even reverted all my code from source control and get the same issues from a version of the site from before my current changes.

Note:

- After I restart my machine and go into VS and Rebuild I get this error: "The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded." Rebuild again and I get the above collision error.
- I can Build the site and hit it successfully locally, but publishing the files still ends in the same scenario above
- No changes were made to the "Breadcrumb.ascx" control referenced in the error

My machine credentials are:

- Windows Vista
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- I have Admin rights

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So let's guess: "...I have even reverted all my code from source control...". Did you removed the `bin` and `obj` of every project included in solution? Some teams send those files to source control too.

Comment: ¿Did you try to Clear your solution? Search for duplicate class name on all the project's files. Try to change your project's location files. Check too your namespace's names. Last solution is change your ascx class name :(

Comment: Yes, I removed all bin/obj files and I renamed the control class names too.

Phx: What is the process to clear my solution?

Comment: Just right here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/254898

Comment: Hi Phx: I don't have that option, just Rebuild Solution, which doesn't work. Is that something for Web apps as opposed to sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of colleagues at work we fixed this issue by manually installing .Net 4.5. I can now Rebuild Solution and Publish (which creates the *.compile) files.

*What we believe happened is that our infrastructure team installed Windows updates over the weekend, because on Friday everything worked, and on Monday found our computers rebooted, and nothing worked.*

Comment: One of my colleagues recently came across [**this article**](http://ydie22.blogspot.com/2008/11/aspnetcompiler-and-missing-compiled.html), which explains that McAfee virus scanning can be the culprit: